# Solution for catching error & report errors in application

Tags: c#, architecture

I see in some applications, when a bug happens, a dialog will appear with error detail, and it also includes a Send button to send this error detail to my logging server. You will see this feature in Firefox web browser.

Please help me to implement this feature in .NET.
Thanks.

Comment: This is a very broad question.  Is there any specific piece you need help with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += 
    new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException)

Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
```

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions

Comment: I agree that this is the best solution.  Was about to post this link, but you beat me to the punch: http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/07/top-level-exception-handling-in-windows-forms-applications-%E2%80%93-code-listing-1/

Comment: I wonder the best solution which can help me fix application bugs easiest. That means the solution can log error in detail so that I can find the error reason and fix it. Thanks.

Comment: You could use a logging framework like nlog to print the stacktrace of the exception and write it to disk or send it up to a web servcie.